# symfony2 form collection with an empty row

Tags: forms, symfony

I have a form with an collection:

```
$builder->add('languages', 'collection', array(
    'type'           => new LanguageType(),
    'allow_add'      => true,
    'allow_delete'   => true,
    'by_reference'   => false
));
```

In the twig-template I render an additional row with an empty (LanguageType). For that I use the prototype and replace the **name**.

In the Controller I bind the Request and discard the "empty" Language in the setter:

```
public function addLanguage($lang)
{
    if($lang->getLanguage())
    {
        $this->languages->add($lang);
    }
    // discard the others
}
```

For some Reason the "empty" row throws an validation error via the NotBlank validator.

My only working solution is to remove the empty row from the raw-Request but thats ugly.

Comment: What does LanguageType() look like? What are you changing the empty form's name to?

Comment: The LanguageType is very simple: $builder->add('lang')

Comment: It's not dirty, really, otherwise the only alternative solution would be to set the option `required` to false on `$builder->add('lang')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution is valid.

Otherwise you could set the option `required` to `false` on `$builder->add('lang')` but then you would have to do some extra checking yourself.

```
$builder->add('lang', 'text', array(
    'required' => false
));
```

Documentation about the [required option](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/text.html#required).

Or you can create some JS code that injects the name of the input only when the field is not empty (input with an empty name doesn't have its value sent through). It isn't great either but it works.